# Construct a sequence that satisfies the following property.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'm studying for a test tomorrow and I'm stuck on this question currently. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Construct a sequence {$x_k$} $\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with the property that for any x $\in{\mathbb{R}^2}$, there exists a subsequence {$x_{k_n}$} which converges to x

Answer (score 1):

Make your $\{x_{k}\}$ an enumeration of any countable dense subset of ${\bf R}^2$.  For example, form $\{x_{k}\}$ by enumerating all the points in ${\bf R}^2$ with rational coordinates.

Comment: hey i appreciate the reply. this is my first course in this topic so its really new to me and that was what I initially thought as well but what about irrational numbers?? shouldn't they be represented as well??

Comment: Why, they will. Any irrational number is a limit of some sequences of rational numbers, isn't that so? See: $3,\,3.1,\,3.14,\,3.141,\,3.1415,\,\dots,\,\pi$

Comment: ohhh thanks. yeah it finally clicked. i appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, the subset must be dense in ${\bf R}^2$, which means that *every* point in ${\bf R}^2$ (whether rational or not) can be approximated with arbitrary accuracy by points from the subset.  And "approximated by" translates to "serves as the limit of a sequence of".:)